# How to add completion block to SwiftUI .alert(isPresented)

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to add a completion block to the following code:

```
.alert(isPresented: $booleanHandler) {
   Alert(title: Text("Alert Title"), message: Text("This is an alert message"), 
   dismissButton: .default(Text("Dismiss")) )
```

I have tried adding it in the traditional way with a handler:

```
{ (UIAlertAction) -> Void in ... }
```

But it throws an error, and I'm struggling to find a clear solution in the Swift Documentation.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Alert buttons](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/alert/button) accept an optional action handler as a parameter:

```
Alert(
   title: Text("Alert Title"), message: Text("This is an alert message"), 
   dismissButton: .default(Text("Dismiss")) { 
      print("I'm done") 
   }
)
```